# eventTimezone value

Tags: android, calendar

can anybody help me about what to insert in the eventTimezone value when adding an event to a calendar? this is my code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("title", eventName);
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startCal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endCal.getTimeInMillis());   
    intent.putExtra("eventTimezone","Hong Kong");
    startActivity(intent);
```

everything else works fine but the eventTimezone doesnt seem to change the option of the timezone to my desired timezone. what value do i need? ive tried "GMT+1" and "(GMT+8:00) Hong Kong" but they are not working.

Comment: You can also try Asia/Shanghai

Comment: Sorry but GMT+8:00 did not seem to work.

Comment: another one actually something similar i have used GMT + 8:00 or you can once look for GMT +8:00

Comment: Asia/Shanghai this currently i am using in my code some where.

Comment: you might have a different code than mine. would you mind posting a bit of your code here for me to see/compare. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you get the timezone into it

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, tz.getID());
```